# No error codes on compilation but there is no datatable on the screen and I cannot figure out why

Tags: c#, html, sql, .net, sql-server

The search text box is not returning a valid person datatable on the screen, anyone have any idea why?

**Database class:**

```
static public DataTable SearchButton(string search)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        const string searchQuery = "exec SearchTerm";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(searchQuery, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search_Term", SqlDbType.VarChar, search.Length).Value = "%" + search + "%";
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**PeopleList.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SearchTextbox.Text == null || SearchTextbox.Text == "")
    {
        PeopleListLabel.Text = "Please enter a search term!";
    }
    else
    {
        Phonelist.DataSource = Database.SearchButton(SearchTextbox.Text);
        Phonelist.DataBind();
    }  
}
```

**SQL Stored Procedure:**

```
print 'SearchTerm'
if exists (select * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id(N'[SeachTerm]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    drop procedure SearchTerm

go
    create procedure SearchTerm 
        @Search_Term varchar(64) = null
    as
    begin
    set nocount on;

    SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address, gender, home_address, home_city, home_state, home_zip_code, telephone_number
    FROM person
    WHERE first_name LIKE @Search_Term OR last_name LIKE @Search_Term
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the search parameter within single quotes.

Replace This:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search_Term", SqlDbType.VarChar, search.Length).Value 
    = "%" + search + "%";
```

With This:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search_Term", SqlDbType.VarChar, search.Length).Value 
    = "'%" + search + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing commandType.

```
static public DataTable SearchButton(string search)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            const string searchQuery = "exec SearchTerm";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(searchQuery, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search_Term", SqlDbType.VarChar, search.Length).Value = "'%" + search + "%'";
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it didn't quite work though, the DataTable is returning a null value but the search term is returning what is input into the searchbox. therefore nothing is populating the table?(sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: @Jake: enclose search parameter within single quotes try ->  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search_Term", SqlDbType.VarChar, search.Length).Value = "'%" + search + "%'";`